# How to do LESS @import without @import literally?

Tags: css, less

I'm using LESS. From Google PageSpeed I've learnt that, using `@import` in CSS file will hamper the site speed. So I'd like to exclude any `@import` thing from my CSS. I have 2 different stylesheets `reset.css`, and `rebuild.css` - to avoid `@import` I copied all of their code into my main stylesheet. So the real styles of my site got below many code and that's a problem. So I need the two stylesheets to `@import` into the `styles.less` (main stylesheet) file, in a way, so that, they actually won't generate any @import when I'm compiling them with **WinLESS** into pure `styles.css`. I want them to insert physically into the style.css when I'll compile the `styles.less` into `styles.css`.

I want `styles.less` like:

```
@import('reset.css');
@import('rebuild.css');

/* SITE STYLES HERE */
```

But want the rendered `styles.css` to be:

```
code from reset.css
code from rebuild.css

/* THEN, SITE STYLES HERE */
```

I'm using **WinLESS** to compile the CSS file from LESS, and NOT USING `.less` with JavaScript directly, but using the `styles.css` only.

Comment: If you are using `@import` inside the LESS file, it will include it automatically for you, and compile it, so you would see the whole code in your generated `.css` file instead of `@import`. So you should get what you want, and you did it well. Check it again, and if it's not including the whole code, then something is either configured differently or there is an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
@import (less) 'reset.css';
@import (less) 'rebuild.css';

/* SITE STYLES HERE */
```

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks. I'm using PHPStorm, and it's showing a red error sign on the file, though the compilation is doing good and working fine, but I'm just worried about the error sign, is it simply a PHPStorm disabilities to not understanding the inner syntax of LESS like `(less)`?

Comment: I don't have PHPStorm installed, so honestly I don't know for sure. But most likely, yes, it looks like it just fails to interpret this syntax on its own.

Comment: Wonderful ! is there some place where this behaviour is documented ?

Comment: @BiAiB See [Import Directives](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an `import` statement in your  less file. it will be included (css code is inserted) in your result css file.

read more on winless [example page](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler#) (click on `Importing`)

Example:
styles.less:

```
@import('other.less');
.myOtherClass {
    // other rules
}
```

other.less:

```
.myClass {
    // rules
}
```

after compiling using winless (or any other less compiler); result.css:

```
.myClass {
    // rules
}
.myOtherClass {
    // other rules
}
```