# LESS Minified CSS and WordPress Theme CSS header

Tags: css, wordpress, less, minify

I'm developing a WordPress theme, and using LESS for the CSS. LESS has many dynamic solution, and I found them helpful throughout my project. I'm using LESS, but not directly, I'm compiling the LESS file into CSS and enqueueing them (.css) into the site `<head>`. To compile the LESS files, I'm using WinLESS (v. 1.8.1), and it's an excellent and quick one. It has a built-in minfication technique so that with a single click I can **(1)** Compile the LESS file, and **(2)** Minify them at once. To ensure site speed I'd like to prefer the minified version of the CSS. But...

But, we all know that a WordPress theme CSS file contains the theme information at the header, like:

```
/*
Theme Name: my theme
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/
Description: my theme description
Author: you
Author URI: http://www.example-author.com/
Version: 1.0
*/
```

If I command WinLESS to compile my `style.less` to `Compile && Minify` then I get a minified version to `style.css`, but you know a minified CSS doesn't contain any CSS comments, so the theme information simply blown by the process. And in `wp-admin/themes.php` page the theme become header-less (unnamed).

I then tried something different. I made my stylesheet into two files:

- `style.less` - contains **only** the header information a theme needs, nothing else
- `my-site.less` - contains all the site CSS

I am compiling the `style.css` as non-minified, but the `my-site.css` as minified. In `style.less` I am including or taking all the CSS from the `my-site.css` with:

```
@import (less) 'css/my-site.css`;
```

So that, the minified `my-site.css` is completely imported to the `style.css` file (there would be **no** `@import` CSS parameter there). They will be included like the regular CSS codes, line-by-line, with the `(less)` included [[details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281919/how-to-do-less-import-without-import-literally)].

**PROBLEMS...**
That's actually the problem. Though I'm importing a minified CSS file, but the LESS `@import (less)` is taking the declarations as line-by-line.

Where my `my-site.css` is like:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}html{margin:0;padding:0}
```

when I'm opening the `style.css` file it's like:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The importing is vanishing the minification completely.

Is there any other solution to @import CSS codes into a stylesheet being minified?

**P.S.:** I'm completely aware about the **WP-Minify** plugin (a nice one), and I don't actually want to use it on the first hand.

Comment: It it using yui-compress? Try starting the WordPress comment with `/*!` rather than just `/*`. (That's recognised by the yui minifier as a comment you specifically want to keep...) I'm hoping that'll keep the comment, but still allow WordPress to recognise it.

Comment: `/*!` is also recognised by LESS built-in minifier, so most likely it will do the trick.

Comment: @MattGibson: Bulls Eye! That's what that it should be. Thanks a lot. Saved a lot of trouble. Would love to mark this as an answer, if you make this as an Answer to the Question. :) Thank you with love.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WinLess uses the YUI compressor to do its minifying. (Well, specifically, I think WinLess uses LESS.js, which uses YUI compress.) Because of this, you can use a particular starting comment style -- `/*!` to hint to the minifier that the comment should be kept:

```
/*!
Theme Name: my theme
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/
Description: my theme description
Author: you
Author URI: http://www.example-author.com/
Version: 1.0
*/
```

WordPress should still recognise the block comment and use the theme information.

See the ["special comments" section of the YUI compressor documentation](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/css.html).